# how can I use 'vue3-google-oauth' with boot files in Quasar?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am trying to implement Google OAuth2 using 'vue3-google-oauth'.

I tried the method below, but the signIn() function returned false.

Please tell me how to use 'vue3-google-oauth' with boot files in Quasar.

this is my code.

googleoauth.js

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers';
import GAuth from 'vue3-google-oauth2';

let app;
export default boot(({ app }) => {
  const gAuthOption = {
    clientId: '835170725866-nt6qibip4tb7jafav2k20j83ipso67mo.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scope: 'profile email',
    prompt: 'select_account',
  };
  app.use(GAuth, gAuthOption);

  app = app;
});

export { app };
```

quasar.config.js

```
...

boot: ['googleoauth'],
...
```

LoginPage.vue ----- I want to use Google OAuth2 in this file

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

const app = getCurrentInstance();


app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$gAuth.signIn(); // return false (not working)
```

Comment: any luck implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me just by adding this way...
without export

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import vue3GoogleLogin from 'vue3-google-login'

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  app.use(vue3GoogleLogin, {
    clientId: '682552864402.apps.googleusercontent.com'
  })
})
```